# Thumbnails don't appear in Magento except if I save the product

Tags: magento, magmi

I've looked around for answers, but none of them seem to apply to my case.

The product's images were changed via Magmi with a csv file with the following structure:

```
"sku","image","small_image","thumbnail"
```

They were changed from png to jpg files.

I've refreshed all 7 cache types, I've flushed catalog images cache, I've flushed Magento cache. I haven't flushed cache storage because the warning message scared me...

If I open the product in the admin area I see the images are properly set. If I save the product, the images appear correctly in the catalog view. This leads me to believe it's a problem with indexes or temporary files. I was thinking it could be the Category Products index, but Magmi updates that while importing products.

I've cleared the browser's cache... I'm out of ideas.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Main_Page

Comment: Try refreshing ALL of your indexes (not just Category Products).  Also try deleting everything in the `/media/catalog/product/cache` folder.  It's ok to clear your Cache Storage.  The error message is just saying that other applications may use that directory for temporary files.

Comment: did you find out how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Reindex manually through command line:
$ php /yoursite/shell/indexer.php --reindexall

Greetings.